# How to compute the Laurent series

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How would you find the Laurent Series for this function:

$$f(z) = z^2 + \frac {1}{z^2 - 2z + 10}$$

So I know the singular points are $ z = 1+3i$ and $z=1-3i$
and then I changed the function into

$$f(z) = z^2 + \frac{\frac{1}{6i}}{z-(1+3i)} - \frac{\frac{1}{6i}}{z-(1-3i)} $$
Then I can do a Laurent series on general formula $\frac{1}{z-a}$

Am I on the right track?
And what would be the principal and analytic parts of the series?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no one Laurent series for $f$.  There are differing Laurent series about different points as you point out.  For example, let's consider the Laurent series about $z=1+i 3$.  Then letting $\zeta=z-1-i 3$:

$$\begin{align}f(z) &= [(\zeta + 1+i 3]^2 + \frac1{i 6}  \frac1{\zeta} -\frac1{i 6} \frac1{\zeta+i 6}\\ &=+ \frac1{i 6}  \frac1{\zeta} + \frac1{36} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{-i \zeta}{6} \right )^k -8+i 6 + 2(1+i 3) \zeta +\zeta^2 \end{align}$$

This way, you can read each of the coefficients of $\zeta$ off from the series and the quadratic provided.  Note that this Laurent series also includes the pole and its coefficient is the residue of $f$ at the pole.